# How to Use WhereIn Query in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**Controller**

```php
    public function detail(Peserta $peserta)
    {
        // get konfirmasi_id
        $konfirmasi = KonfirmasiPembayaran::where('email',$peserta->email)->select('id')->get();

        $payments   = BankSettlement::whereIn('konfirmasi_id',array($konfirmasi->id))->get();
        // dd($payments);
        $tagihan    = Tagihan::where([['peserta_id', $peserta->id],['type', 3]])->first();
        return view('data.peserta.detail', ['data' => $peserta, 'payments' => $payments,'tagihan' => $tagihan]);
    }
```

I want to display data from BankSettlement based on konfirmasi_id. Here I try to use WhereIn Query like this, but still error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.".

[image: konfirmasi variable]

$konfirmasi has data like the image above.

What is the correct way to display data from BankSettlement based on konfirmasi_id ? Thankyou

Comment: konfirmasi_id is array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this changes:

```
    $konfirmasi = KonfirmasiPembayaran::where('email',$peserta->email)->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $payments   = BankSettlement::whereIn('konfirmasi_id',$konfirmasi)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to change a collection to array.
`$payments=BankSettlement::whereIn('konfirmasi_id',array($konfirmasi->id))->get();`

You should do this

```
public function detail(Peserta $peserta)
    {
        // get konfirmasi_id
        $konfirmasi = KonfirmasiPembayaran::where('email',$peserta->email)
                         ->select('id')
                         ->get()
                         ->pluck('id')
                         ->toArray(); //This will return an array of ids

        $payments   = BankSettlement::whereIn('konfirmasi_id',$konfirmasi)->get();
        // dd($payments);
        $tagihan    = Tagihan::where([['peserta_id', $peserta->id],['type', 3]])->first();
        return view('data.peserta.detail', ['data' => $peserta, 'payments' => $payments,'tagihan' => $tagihan]);
    }
```

Edit:
Read [Laravel Collections|Pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have to reuse the result of `$konfirmasi` then it would be better to use subquery. Writing a subquery is optimized way. if you write two different query then there will be two seperate database connection request.

[Laravel subquery](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses)

```
$konfirmasi = KonfirmasiPembayaran::where('email',$peserta->email)->select('id');

$payments   = BankSettlement::whereIn('konfirmasi_id', $konfirmasi )->get();
```